# Account checker in python

Tags: python

I trying to build account checker in python,
when i run scripts to check the account is working or not like a u can sign in on website with that username and password or not.
i getting always failed to login and when i try to put my real account in combo.json still cant login into website idk why

i trying to my scripts can login into website with combo.json check the accont status if is working say u loggined or say login failed like that

```
import sys
import requests
import json

def check_credentials(username, password):
    req = requests.session()
    param = {"username": username, "password": password}
    response = req.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login", data=param)
    if response.status_code == 200 and "incorrect" not in response.text:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    try:
        with open("combo.json", "r") as file:
            combos = json.load(file)
            for combo in combos:
                username = combo["username"]
                password = combo["password"]
                if check_credentials(username, password):
                    print(f"Login successful for: {username}:{password}")
                else:
                    print(f"Login failed for: {username}:{password}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("combo.json file not found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
[
    {"username": "user1", "password": "password1"},
    {"username": "user2", "password": "password2"}
]
```

Comment: I don't think spotify's login works via a POST to that endpoint. I believe they also have a prevention mechanism in place to prevent automated checks such as this.